# How to copy part of a BMP to a canvas?

Tags: delphi

I have a large bitmap (pf24bit). I want to copy only a part (small rectangle) of that image to a canvas. The canvas is double buffered.

`frmTester.Canvas.CopyRect()` will do the trick, but it has two problems:

1. the copied image is a bit corrupted
2. it is damn slow.

BitBlt is super fast, but it will copy the entire bitmap.

Comment: "BitBlt is super fast, but it will copy the entire bitmap." No, that's not right.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - This is the documentation of BitBlt. The parameters for Src are only X,Y. Not a full TRect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt

Comment: Yes, you got `x1` and `x2`. But you also got `cx` and `cy`: "The width, in logical units, of the source and destination rectangles." and "The height, in logical units, of the source and the destination rectangles." So you can copy only a small part of the source. However, `BitBlt` will never *scale* the part you copy. But [`StretchBlt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt) will.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - Thanks. It worked. If you post your comment as Short answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `BitBlt` is super fast, but it will copy the entire bitmap.

Actually, no: [`BitBlt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) allows you to copy only a rectangular part of the source, specified using the `x1`, `y1`, `cx`, and `cy` parameters.

However, the same width and height are used for the source and the destination rectangles, so `BitBlt` cannot be used to stretch (or scale) the part you copy.

[`StretchBlt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt) lets you do this, though.

Comment: The original cX, cY parameters are redeclared  in Delphi as Width & Height. Once I have fixed on that, my brain refused to take in the correct information from the official API documentation page :)